# Writing JSON file using for loop

Tags: java, json

I am writing data to a JSON file using a for loop, my question is will all the data be written to the file or a new .json file will be created every time?

```java
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("abc");
list.add("def");
list.add("xyz");
for (String name : list) {
  JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
  obj.put("Name:", name);
  try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\elements.json")) {
    file.write(obj.toJSONString());         
    file.flush();       
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please update your code like this.

```
...
FileWriter file = new FileWriter("C:\Users\elements.json")
for (String name : list) {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

    obj.put("Name:", name);

    file.write(obj.toJSONString());
}
file.flush();
...
```

Otherwise, please use string variable to store all json as one string variable and write the string variable to file at once.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you can use Jackson's ObjectMapper to map the entire list object.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("abc");
list.add("def");
list.add("xyz");

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.writeValue(new File("elements.json"), list);
```